# How to show ONLY a VF page to a user?

Tags: visualforce, profile, user, home-page-layout

On login, the user must ONLY be shown a VF page.

My thoughts :

1. Make a VF page.
2. Make a VF page TAB.
3. Set tab hidden for ALL profiles except our own (say Prof.), which is default on.
4. In our profile, set ALL tabs as hidden except our own.

However, the HOME tab will still be shown.

How to fix this?

Comment: Maybe you should be using Community or Site?

Answer (score 1):

You can do the next steps

1. Create a visualforce.
2. Create a app and set default page is the visualforce.
3. Duplicate a Profile for that user and in the profile configurate that only can access to the new visualforce

Answer (score 0):

SFDC does not allow us to remove home tab from setup. If you try to do so you will get error.

But, there is workaround for this.

You can run JS code and hide the home tab.

For ex. Bellow page hide home tab and just display VF page.

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="true">
  <!-- Begin Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
  <h1>Congratulations</h1>

  <script>
      console.log(document.getElementById('home_Tab'));
      document.getElementById('home_Tab').style.display = 'none';    
  </script>
  This is your new Page
  <!-- End Default Content REMOVE THIS -->
</apex:page>
```

- create vf page with above code
- create new tab with above vf page
- create app with above tab and home tab
- note that you cannot remove home tab from tab list of app make vf page tab as default tab for this app
- removed access to all other apps for given user only app created in step 3 should be accessible

  You should be all set

Comment: But this is a VF page... how are we supposed to display it?

Comment: by looking at your question i thought you already know that. .... Make a VF page TAB

Comment: I said display... where do I put this?

Comment: Check my updated answer